# How to fix ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID error in jquery datatables?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, datatable

Good day. I'm developing a C# website for internal company use and utilize the jquery data table cdn on the site. For most users including myself, the page works fine. However, for certain users, the following error can be seen on the console when trying to load the jquery data table cdn on a page.

```
Failed to load resource:         cdn.datatables.net/v...atatables.min.css.1
net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

Failed to load resource:         cdn.datatables.net/v...earchPane.min.css.1
net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

Failed to load resource:         cdn.datatables.net/v...ataTables.min.css.1
net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID
.
.
.
```

So far, we've tried restarting, clearing the cache and debugging the code itself, all to no avail. Please assist.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know
this error only when **the browser does not trust the certificate for some reason**.

**Check the browser certificate restriction and limitation**

If you are using development certificate it's may the cause as they are generally self-sign certificate